# ASP.Net Faulty Link Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have just created a link to route in **Site.Master** but it have created a weird error 
For example, when it was clicked, instead of `http://localhost/Admin/ManageType` it became `http://localhost/~/Admin/ManageType`.

I have tried to solve it myself by removing `~/` and it works but it come with a flaw. Once click it work and bring you to the page but when click again, it become `http://localhost/Admin/Admin/ManageType` instead of `http://localhost/~/Admin/ManageType`.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Manage <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="Admin/ManageType">Recipe</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="Admin/ManageType">Type</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Recipe/Recipe">Recipe</a></li>     
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Control.ResolveUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) method instead.
And you need to change:

```
<li><a href="Admin/ManageType">Recipe</a></li>
```

To:

```
<li><a href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Admin/ManageType") %>" title="ManageType" >ManageType</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Much appreciated

Comment: Glad I Could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li><a href="~/Admin/ManageType" runat="server">Type</a></li>
```

Comment: Does not work as mentioned in Description. It just create `http://localhost:32375/Admin/~/Admin/ManageType` and show error page

Comment: You omitted the runat="server" attribute in the links causing this problem.

Comment: This is why the Page.ResolveUrl method offered in Div's answer works for you in this case.